# Asp.Net website running properly in Internet Explorer but not properly in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm making a website in Asp.Net.

When I'm running it in Internet Explorer it's working fine but When I'm running it in Firefox it's a mess.

Alignment of controls are changed and effect of .css is lost in firefox.

Is there any solution to make my website compatible with firefox?

```
.form-group .help-block:not(.error) {
  display: block !important;
 }
.form-control {
  height: 28px; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
 }
 .col-md-10
 {
   width: 50%;
 }
 .navbar .nav > li > a {
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
 }
 .navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
 .navbar .nav > li > a:focus {
 color: #000;
 background: #529e9b;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
 }
```

Firefox Version 26.0
Internet Explorer 8

The main problem is miss alignment of all controls in firefox.

Comment: Put some code (css) which is running in IE but not running in firfox?

Comment: At a bare minimum we will need your CSS to assess cross-browser compatibility. If the site is live a link will also be helpful, but still post your CSS here as the question will then be useful to future users (long after you have fixed your site). Which version(s) of Internet Explorer and Firefox are you testing in?

Comment: Additionally, is it a web forms or MVC application?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ, I've edited my code. It is web forms application.

Comment: @pwdst, it is web forms application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css there is a class ".col-md-10" and I am assuming you are using Bootstrap. Why are you defining a property of width: 50% for 10 columns while you can simply use "col-md-6" to achieve the 50% width instead of overriding the bootstrap property?

For your question:
Different browsers render html and css differently. In your case Firefox will render some css properties different than IE8. You have to write different css for different browsers. You don't have to rewrite all the rules in every css file but only the properties which mess the style up.

You can use main css files for all the browsers and in the head section of your page/view you can define css for IE.
Following css will target all the versions of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In href there is the name of the css file wich defines the specific rules for the IE only.

if following css rule is being rendered in IE differently

```
.navbar .nav > li
 {
    width:20px;
 }
```

You need to only define this rule in the css for IE to fix the problem and IE will automatically take the defined rule in the css specified for the IE in our case it is
"all-ie-only.css".

if you want to go the other way around (Like in your case your code is working fine in IE but not in Firefox) so you can use the main css files for IE and define css for the browsers other than IE, you can use the following code in the head section:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can define css even for different version of ie in the following manner:
For IE8 only:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

For IE7 only:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

I hope this helps.

Here is a nice article about using different css for IE
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some things :

1. have small script which will check which browser & it's version you are running on.
2. Write to different .css classes for different browsers.
3. Check browser & it's version then apply appropriate .css classes.
   For e.g.

> ```
> if (strBrowserVersion == "Microsoft Internet Explorer6" || strBrowserVersion == "Microsoft Internet Explorer7")
> {
>    $('#OrderHeaderAll colgroup').find('col:eq(' + 5 + ')').css({ 'width': '60px' });
> }
> else
> {
>    $('#OrderHeaderAll colgroup').find('col:eq(' + 5 + ')').css({ 'width': '0px' });
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not using css for only one control. I'm using 3-4 different css files. It is not possible that for each style I put this condition.

Comment: @netX:Can you show some dummy piece of the content(.css) that you've done. Specifically where it mess.